# Build a large array from a small array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, repeat

If I have a small array like a=[1 2 3 4 5], and want to build a large array from it with repeating it, like b=[1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ....1 2 3 4 5], how can I do that in simplest way and lowest calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

repmat is what you are looking for

```
n = 5    
b = repmat(a,1,n)
```